# What does "On Sundays, this service is two hourly in both directions" mean?

Tags: meaning

> On Sundays, this service is two hourly in both directions.

I don't understand the sentence, especially the two hourly part in this sentence

can anyone help?

Comment: You omit vital context. If it's a transport service, two buses / trains etc should go past a given point on the route every two hours, one in each direction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's about a transportation service, let's say buses. The sentence means there is a bus every two hours, in both directions on this line. See also [the Wiktionary definition of "two hourly"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two-hourly).

Comment: thank you. have a nice day.

Comment: This meaning is unknown in most of the US.  It would be read as "twice hourly" if it were deciphered at all.